# Websocket server that receives the command and sends it back to all connected clients

Tags: websocket, websocket-sharp

I would like to create a websocket server that receives the command and sends it back to all connected clients. Basically, it makes the programs able to communiciate with each other. Can you tell me where to begin?

Comment: Can anyone comment on it?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many implemented solutions for that which provide the implementation like `socket.io`, `Firebase Real time database`, `signalr` and many other.

Comment: Google that! -_-